# Space before chapters titles in ClassicThesis

Tags: spacing, chapters, classicthesis

I want to add some space before the chapters titles in `classicthesis` to get an effect like [this](http://web.ict.kth.se/~ghb/publications/documents/Gabriel%20Hjort%20Blindell%20-%20Synthesizing%20Software%20From%20a%20ForSyDe%20Model%20Targeting%20GPGPUs.pdf) thesis so I have modified the `classicthesis.sty` in this manner:

---

```
% chapters
\ifthenelse{\boolean{@linedheaders}}%
{% lines above and below, number right
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]%             
    {\relax}{\vspace*{0.125\textheight}{\raggedleft{\color{Maroon}\chapterNumber\thechapter} \\ }}{0pt}%
    {\titlerule\vspace*{.9\baselineskip}\raggedright\spacedallcaps}[\normalsize\vspace*{.8\baselineskip}\titlerule]%
}{% something like Bringhurst  
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]%
    {\relax}{\vspace*{0.25\textheight}{\mbox{}\oldmarginpar{\vspace*{-3\baselineskip}\color{Maroon}\chapterNumber\thechapter}}}{0pt}%
    {\raggedright\spacedallcaps}[\normalsize\vspace*{.8\baselineskip}\titlerule]% 
}
```

---

I want to ask you if this is the right manner to put that space and if the space is put in the right quantity.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's never a good idea to modify directly a `.sty` file; that said, `classicthesis` uses the `titlesec` package to format the sectional unit headings and, in particular, it uses

```
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{1\baselineskip}{1.2\baselineskip}
```

to control the space before and after chapter titles, so you can simply change the third (space after) and fourth (space after) arguments according to your needs; you can do this in the preamble of your document without changing `classicthesis.sty`. A simple example:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a5paper,footinclude=true,headinclude=true]{scrbook}
\usepackage[linedheaders,parts,pdfspacing]{classicthesis} % ,manychapters
\usepackage{lipsum}

\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{*12}{*7}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents 

\chapter{Test Chapter One}
\section{A Section}
\lipsum[1-6]
\chapter{Test Chapter One}
\lipsum[1]
\section{A Section}
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Of course, instead of the values I used (refer to the documentation for `titlesec`) you can use any valid length.

[image]

If the changes in spacing must apply only to numbered chapters, instead of using `\titlespacing`, a solution using `\titleformat` to discriminate between numbered and unnumbered chapters (with the help of the `numberless` key) can be used; in the following code I illustrate this approach in the case of the `lineheaders` option; for numbered chapters a space of `8\baselineskip` was added before the title and `2\baselineskip` was added after the tile; unnumbered chapters maintain their original settings:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a5paper,footinclude=true,headinclude=true]{scrbook}
\usepackage[linedheaders,parts,pdfspacing]{classicthesis} % ,manychapters
\usepackage{lipsum}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]%             
  {\vspace*{8\baselineskip}}{\raggedleft{\color{halfgray}\chapterNumber\thechapter} \\ }
  {0pt}{\titlerule\vspace*{.9\baselineskip}\raggedright\spacedallcaps}
  [\normalsize\vspace*{.8\baselineskip}\titlerule\vspace*{2\baselineskip}]
\titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}[display]%             
  {\relax}{}
  {0pt}{\titlerule\vspace*{.9\baselineskip}\raggedright\spacedallcaps}
  [\normalsize\vspace*{.8\baselineskip}\titlerule]

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents 

\chapter{Test Chapter One}
\section{A Section}
\lipsum[1-6]
\chapter{Test Chapter One}
\lipsum[1]
\section{A Section}
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Comment: at how much correspond `*12` or `*7` in fraction of `\baselineskip` or in fraction of `\textheight` or in `pt` ? and what kind of measurement is it?

Comment: @FormlesCloud `\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{*12}{*7}` means 12 times `1ex plus .3ex minus .06ex` and 7 times `1ex plus .1ex` (see Section **3.2. Spacing** of the documentation, specially page 5).

Comment: to make your spacing quantity in fraction of `\textheight` i have put `\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{.1622\textheight}{.085\textheight}` is right? where can i read some tips to put a space typographically correct, before and after the chapters titles? or can you give me that tips? and another things, how much difference there is in vertical spacing between the normal chapters and the `linedheaders` option ?

Comment: @FormlessCloud First question: yes. Second question: *correct* spacing before and after chapter titles is a very subjective matter and depends on many other attributes of the overall layout (something that is *correct* in some cases might not be in other); a professional typographer might give you some hints. Third question: you can chech `classicthesis.sty` to see the difference (see comment below).

Comment: @FormlessCloud linedheaders: `\titleformat{\chapter}[display] {\relax}{\raggedleft{\color{halfgray}\chapterNumber\thechapter} \\ }{0pt}{\titlerule\vspace*{.9\baselineskip}\raggedright\spacedallcaps}[\normalsize\vspace*{.8\baselineskip}\titlerule]` without linedheaders: `\titleformat{\chapter}[display] {\relax}{\mbox{}\oldmarginpar{\vspace*{-3\baselineskip}\color{halfgray}\chapterNumber\thechapter}}{0pt} {\raggedright\spacedallcaps}[\normalsize\vspace*{.8\baselineskip}\titlerule]`. Basically there's a small difference due to the rules.

Comment: thnaks ! but how can i space only the numbered chapters with titlesec? obviously i don't want the space before the table of contents or the abstract...

Comment: @FormlessCloud I've added one possible solution in my updated answer.